# Configuring an emailAdapter for parse-server?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, email

I was trying to configure an emailadapter for my parse server (on AWS), and the needed configuration for my index.js are shown bellow

```
verifyUserEmails: true,
publicServerURL: 'http://MY_HEROKU_APP.herokuapp.com/parse', 
appName: 'MY_APP',
emailAdapter: {
    module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
    options: {
      fromAddress: 'no-reply@example.com',
      domain: 'example.com',
      apiKey: 'key-XXXXXX',
    }
}
```

My question is what are options domain and apiKey, and from where i can get them ?

Answer (score 1):

The default adapter is mailgun so in order to use it you need to do the following steps:

1. go to https://www.mailgun.com/ and create new account (don't worry, you can send up to 10000 email per month for free)
2. After creating the account you will be able to get the apiKey, domain and from address

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks, but when i was trying to add a domain on mailgun it show me this message "Your account is temporarily disabled." , why ?

Comment: I enabled my account by contacting the Support Center.